# What's the utility of parserJob in Apache Nutch?

Tags: parsing, nutch

I can't find any useful documentation about it, like injector, generator, fetcher and dbUpdater.
I need to understand what does it do.
I'm using nutch 2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both versions 1.x/2.x parsing refers to the same concept: extract useful information out of the web page that was previously fetched.

Of course "useful" is a very broad term. In a more Nutch focused view this usually means running all the parse filter plugins, (each plugin is responsible for doing one specific job). For instance, the `parse-metatags` plugin will extract specific (configured) metatags and allow you to store that in your backend. By default Nutch only tries to extract the textual content of the web page and some additional info like the title, headers, etc.